# Access IP address on different subnet without gateway

Tags: iproute, subnets

I have an [USR-TCP232-S2](https://www.usriot.com/products/ttl-ethernet-module.html) IP-to-Serial converter and I would like to access it over Ethernet to set it up.

The module comes with a fixed IP address 192.168.0.7.

My PC (Lubuntu 18.04) is however on a different subnet (192.168.1.0/24, IP address 192.168.1.80, gateway 192.168.1.235), so I can't talk to the module directly.

I expected to be able to reach the module if I added a second IP address to my interface:

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.6/24 dev enp2s0
```

but that didn't work, I got:

```
root@lbox0:~# telnet 192.168.0.7 80
Trying 192.168.0.7...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

I guess I might have to set up a route, using `ip route`, to get to my module.
But I couldn't find anything that involves just an IP address, wihtout using a gateway.

Output of `ip addr` and `ip route`:

```
root@lbox0:~# ip addr show dev enp2s0
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:e5:49:84:2b:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.80/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 686535sec preferred_lft 686535sec
    inet 192.168.0.6/24 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c553:9525:6f96:5b5b/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@lbox0:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.235 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.6
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.80 metric 100
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ip addr show dev enp2s0` and also `ip route` ?

Comment: @bitinerant Added requested info

Comment: Those network settings look fine to me. I confirmed on my Ubuntu 18.04 that `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host` just means that it cannot reach the IP, and not that there is a problem with the routing or network set-up. You say that the device's IP address is 192.168.0.7. Is there some way to confirm this or otherwise confirm that the device is working and connected?

Comment: on your link: "Support DHCP, automatically obtain an IP address". Sure you can't get it to use DHCP (or maybe it did already)?

Comment: @bitinerant That is the problem: I don't know if the IP side works; I can talk to it over the AT command interface over the serial port. I am writing a Python application to set the module up using the AT interface - but this requires physical access to the serial port on the device. It would also be nice if I could do the set-up remotely over IP.

Comment: If there is a possibility that it has an address from DHCP, try to find it on port 80 via `nmap -p 80 192.168.1.*` or log into your router and look at DHCP leases. Or maybe there's an AT command to view the device's IP address.

Comment: @A.B For DHCP to work, the module's IP address must be in the same subnet as the DHCP server. But, unless I can access the module, I can't set it up for DHCP. Sort of a Chicken-and-Egg problem. I guess I will have to try their Windows-based tools to see if the module responds at all.

Comment: You said, "the module's IP address must be in the same subnet as the DHCP server." I'm not sure I understand. A DHCP client requests an IP address from the router, including the subnet of the router.

Comment: @bitinerant Yes, you are correct. I tried your nmap suggestion and I found the module at IP address 192.168.1.11. When I opened the web page, the module was configured as DHCP (the other option is static IP, defaulting to 192.168.0.7). So it seems it was shipped with DHCP as opposed to Static IP.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for letting us know. I think it would be helpful for everyone if you put this in an answer - so that it's easy to find and also so the question is not left unanswered.

Comment: @bitinerant Thanks, added my observations as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the module was shipped configured as `DHCP` instead of `Static IP`.

When I ran `nmap -p80 192.168.1.*`, it found the module at IP address 192.168.1.11.

I was then able to change it to `Static IP`, with IP address 192.168.0.7.

I then couldn't reach the module anymore on IP address 192.168.1.11 and also not on IP address 192.168.0.7.

After I entered `ip addr add 192.168.0.6/24 dev enp2s0`, I could access the module at IP address 192.168.0.7.

This proves that it is sufficient to give your NIC an additional IP address in another subnet to enable access to hosts in that subnet.